# How to get data from GPS Tracking Device to server

Tags: sql, database, gps, tracking

Firstly I'm planning to set up an vehicle tracking system. I have my own server. There is a [device](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-GPS-tracker-Xexun-TK102-2-Free-use-web-account-Android-Iphone-App-NoBox-/291544832455) which can send the data via GPRS. I can define an IP and a port number to this device. I want to connect this device to my server without and auxiliary device. What I want to ask is which format the device send the data(XML, TXT, or something like that), how I can write the data to the database. And if I have to use a computer to get the coordinates from the device, which language should I use?

*I have already read the user manual bu I couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you found solutions?

Comment: @Logicdigger I'm afraid not and I quit the job I was working:)

Comment: No worries i got the solution.

Comment: Do you mind if you can share the solution?